# React Native refreshControl showing before pulldown

Tags: react-native, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented the RefreshControl component which works great, except that when my view initially loads, I see part of another Refresh control showing above the NEW GAME button.  Once I pull down, I get my data and the bug disappears until I restart the app.  Everything else works great but it seems like the 'title', 'tintColor' and 'titleColor' props are causing the problem, because there is no bug without them.

Here is my code:

```
<RefreshControl
   refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
   onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
   title={I18n.t('coming')}
   tintColor="#dceafd"
   titleColor="#dceafd"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just add backgroundColor: 'transparent', i think :)

Comment: I can confirm this works.  My code looks like this: 
`refreshControl={<RefreshControl style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}}  refreshing={this.state.loading} onRefresh={this.refreshItems}/>}`